# how use button "sync projet with gradle files"?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to find this button, but I cannot find.

I tried here

[image]

and

[image: I can not find button]

Comment: Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue with your IDE. I'm using the version 2.2 too and I can see the 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' at the location @CommonsWare mentioned.

Comment: @CommonsWare http://www.mediafire.com/view/m1zavhqq2ie5ax1/3.png

Comment: Perhaps Android Studio is not recognizing your Gradle files. Based on this and your other screenshots, I think you have bigger issues with Android Studio recognizing this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it on your own ;-) Just follow these steps:

1. Open Gradle tool window with `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`
2. Start Macro Recording with `Edit -> Macros -> Start Recording Macro`
3. In Gradle tool window press `Refresh all Gradle projects` button
4. Stop Macro Recording with `Edit -> Macros -> Stop Recording Macro`
5. Save Macro with name `Gradle sync`
6. Press with right mouse button on IntelliJ IDEA toolbar and choose `Customize Menus and Toolbars...`
7. Under `Main menu -> Edit -> Macros -> Macro Actions` find your `Gradle sync` Macro, select it and press `Edit Action Icon...`
8. Download this icon [Sync Project With Gradle Files icon](http://developer.android.com/images/tools/sync-project.png) (from documentation http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) and select this icon in IDEA dialog window
9. Now in `Menus and Toolbars` select last item in `Main Toolbar` group, press `Add After...` and select `All actions -> Macros -> Gradle sync`
10. Now you have `Sync Project with Gradle Files` button!